# to fetch Logged username on Asp.net page in sharepoint

Tags: user-profile-service

Can any one let me know how to fetch a logged username in a asp.net application page running on sharepoint site.
It will be kind if expressed in details..

Regards 
amit

Answer (score 1):

You can use SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser which returns an object of SPUser : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.aspx

Also, SPSecurityContext.GetWindowsIdentity() will return an WindowsIdentity object.

Comment: Just a note. SPSecurityContext.GetWindowsIdentity()  is only available in Sharepoint 2010